# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

[image]TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

What is the problem?
My code

```
import {BrowserRouter as Routes, Route, Router} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
return (
      <div className={stl.container}>
          <Header/>
          <Nav/>

          <Router>
              <Routes>
                  <Route path='/messages'  element={<Messages/>}/>
                  <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfileContent/>}/>
              </Routes>
          </Router>

      </div>

 );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something is wrong with your environment. I had the same issue, reinstalling packages really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the imports. You're importing `BrowserRouter` as `Routes`.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Move the `Nav` component into the Router so it has a routing context provided to it. Any `Link` components rendered need the routing context.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className={stl.container}>
      <Router>
        <Header/>
        <Nav/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/messages'  element={<Messages/>} />
          <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfileContent/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the code still isn't working then check your installed version of `react-router-dom` from your project's directory run:

```
npm list react-router-dom
```

If it is any v6.x version then you should be good. If there's still issue though then I suggest uninstalling and reinstalling `react-router-dom`.

```
npm un -s react-router-dom
npm i -s react-router-dom
```

then run the list command above to validate/verify the installed version.

Comment: I did as you said, shows the same error

Comment: @Els I see. Can you provide a more complete error message and stacktrace? Where is the error and what is being blamed for it? What is undefined that is attempting to read a `pathname` property?

Comment: this is a warning - Element Router doesn't have required attribute history

Comment: @Els Fix your imports, you are mixing up what is imported as a router.

Comment: I changed, something is wrong, look at the new image

Comment: @Els Check your version of `react-router-dom` installed, in the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom`. If `Routes` isn't exported then you may actually have v5.x installed, in this case the `Switch` is the component you want, and the `Route` component API is a bit different.

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.1.1",

Comment: I want to understand why it does not work with this version

Comment: @Els That is the current version. Did you just change the package.json file, or did you actually run `npm i -s react-router-dom` to install it and update the package.json?

Comment: i just looked at the version in json

Comment: @Els Have you checked what version of `react-router-dom` you have installed or uninstalled and installed the latest? Still have an issue?

Comment: the problem is not solved, what do you suggest to do?

Comment: @Els Have you verified what `react-router-dom` version you are on? Like I said, you need to ensure you actually have a v6.x version installed. Or you can just uninstall whatever version is currently there and install latest. From the project directory run `npm un -s react-router-dom; npm i -s react-router-dom`. To check the version run `npm list react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to  you cannot pass an 'undefined' or 'null' value to the attribute, like in my case, I could have added a null-check, but I chose to add a "/" before it, as shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove "/" from the beginning of the path attribute in Route component.
Ex: <Route path='messages'  element={}/>.
Also give the same value to the "to" attribute in Link Component
Ex: Messages

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Must Use Attribute (to="#") with Link and see that this will run

Answer (score 0):

import is in wrong way,

import like this

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

correct sequence is Router then Routes then Route
You are importing Routes Route Router :)

Comment: can you exmplain why ?