# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

***THIS QUESTION IS ALREADY SOLVED. Scroll down or [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73523801/19124473) to view solutions***

I am trying to use React to extract a JSON data from my server and render it with two functions. But it seems that the two render functions cannot read the values in the json correctly.
I'm sure that my data server is working correctly.

Error log:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Source
http://localhost:8080/dist/App.js [:19:68]
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
    at Question (http://localhost:8080/dist/App.js:19:68)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:16313:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:20077:13)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:21590:16)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:27414:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:26548:12)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:26454:5)
    at renderRootSync (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:26422:7)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:26074:20)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-dom.v18.2.0.js:12050:22)
```

App component:

```js
let prop

function App() {
    const [item, setItems] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:9090/')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((resJson) => {
                const data = JSON.parse(resJson)
                setItems(data)
            })
    }, [])
    prop = item
    return (
        <div>
            <Question/>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Question component:

```js
function Question() {
    return (
        <div className={"question"}>
            <h1>{ prop.question.title }</h1>
            <p className={"info"}>Created by user: { prop.question.create_by }</p><br/>
            <p className={"info"}>On { Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(new Date(prop.question.time)) }</p><br/>
            <hr/>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: prop.question.detail}}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

The JSON data:

```json
{
  "question": {
    "title": "Question",
    "create_by": "AZ",
    "time": 1661394765044,
    "detail": "<h4>info</h4>"
  },
  "answers": [
    {
      "create_by": "baa",
      "time": 1661394765044,
      "detail": "<h4>abc</h4>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Arthur, did you try out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497927/15288641) I pasted.

Comment: ofcourse, and there's still some error. And im checking my backend.

Comment: A different one?

Comment: thanks, but im planning to use other js. Because even the example from their official doc went wrong.  Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Hi Arthur, you should be pasting an answer instead of editing the question itself. It's how QA should be here in Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT: I finally solved this problem. Hope it will help you.

There are several problems on frontend and backend.

Frontend:

1. I use `useState` and `useEffect` to hendle fetched data.
   This is my code:

```
const [item, setItems] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:61780/')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setItems(data)
            })
    }, []);
```

2. While reading the json data, do like this: `<level 1>?.<level 2>?.<level 3>`.

**DON'T DO THIS:** `<level 1>.<level 2>.<level 3>`. This will throw out an exception: `Cannot read ... from type 'undefined'`

Example code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './extraUI.css'


function App() {
    const [item, setItems] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:61780/')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setItems(data)
            })
    }, []);
    console.warn(item)

    return (
        <>
            <Question props={item}/>
            <hr/>
            <Answer props={item}/>
        </>
    )
}

function Question({props}) {
    return (
        <div className={"question"}>
            <h1>{ props?.question?.title }</h1>
            <p className={"info"}>Created by user: { props?.question?.create_by }</p><br/>
            <p className={"info"}>On { }</p><br/>
            <hr/>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props?.question?.detail}}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

function Answer({props}) {
    return (
        props?.answers?.map((answer) => {
            return (
                <div className={"answer"}>
                    <h4 className={"info"}>Answer by: { answer?.create_by }</h4><br/>
                    <p className={"info"}>On { Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(new Date(answer?.time)) }</p><br/>
                    <hr/>
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: answer?.detail}}></div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}

export default App;
```

Json data:

```json
{
  "question": {
    "title": "Question",
    "create_by": "AZ",
    "time": 1661394765044,
    "detail": "<h4>info</h4>"
  },
  "answers": [
    {
      "create_by": "baa",
      "time": 1661394765044,
      "detail": "<h4>abc</h4>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Backend:

1. You need to add a header in your server responce: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and it's value is your api url(or you can use `*` if your api is a public one)
   It's like this: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <url or *>`

If you don't do this, it will throw out an exception: `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`. I'm not sure if other js is like this.

Comment: As an aside, `useEffect` should not be used to fetch data. It should be used for subscribing and unsubscribing. To fetch data, use something like `useQuery` from React Query, or Apollo Client, etc.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja Did you mean React Docs is wrong?

Comment: I am repeating what React docs suggest. `useEffect` should be used to perform actions that are repeatable and reversible, such as subscribing and unsubscribing to events. To discourage people from using `useEffect` for data fetch, React v18 in strict mode mounts and unmounts components twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not pure functions, they are components, you cannot share global variables and that is not the way to pass data between components in React, the way to do it correctly is using a context or props, to pass through props I leave you an example of the following way, you should apply this in the other variables too, example:

```
function App() {
    const [item, setItems] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:9090/')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((resJson) => {
                const data = JSON.parse(resJson)
                setItems(data)
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Question title={item.question.title}/>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
}

function Question({title}) {
    return (
        <div className={"question"}>
            <h1>{ title }</h1>
            <p className={"info"}>Created by user: { prop.question.create_by }</p><br/>
            <p className={"info"}>On { Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(new Date(prop.question.time)) }</p><br/>
            <hr/>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: prop.question.detail}}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It seems that it still stuck when calling `{item.question.title}`

Answer (score 0):

First, in `App` remove  `JSON.parse(resJson)` as it's already parsed by `res.json()`. Use some loader while fetching the data as it happens asynchronously, and your component render first. For that give nothing to `useState` as parameter so `item` is `undefined` at the beginning.

```
function App() {
    const [item, setItems] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:9090/')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setItems(data)
            })
    }, []);

    if(!item) return <p>Fetching data...</p>

    return (
        <div>
            <Question question = {item.question}/>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Second, you shouldn't be using global variables to render data in your components when using React, instead use `props` and `state`. To do so, change `Question` component so it receives the data it needs as `props` and notice it's passed in `App` to it:

```
function Question(props) {
    return (
        <div className={"question"}>
            <h1>{ props.question.title }</h1>
            <p className={"info"}>Created by user: { props.question.create_by }</p><br/>
            <p className={"info"}>On { Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(new Date(props.question.time)) }</p><br/>
            <hr/>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.question.detail}}></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```